# Finding area of triangles with Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Iam new to matlab.how i can calculate area of triangles with Matlab code and show in figure?

```
Matlab Code :
```

please help

Comment: Waiting for the `Matlab Code :` to arrive.

Comment: The area can be computed either by `polyarea` (cf. my answer) or any standard formula for triangle areas (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle). It really depends which information you have about your triangle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really didn't specify anything in your question, but here are some suggestions:

```
% some defining vertices
A = [0,1];
B = [1,2];
C = [1,-1];

% collect coordinates
X = [A(1), B(1), C(1)]; % x values
Y = [A(2), B(2), C(2)]; % y values

% compute area
triangle_area = polyarea(X, Y);
disp(['The area of triangle (A,B,C) is ' num2str(triangle_area) '.']);

% plot triangle
figure(1);
fill(X,Y, [0,0.4,0]);
```

**Output**

```
The area of triangle (A,B,C) is 1.5.
```

[image: triangle plot]

Comment: when i run your code show this error : triangle-area
Undefined function or variable 'triangle'.

Comment: cf. answer of Ferdin and check that you copied "triangle_area" instead of "triangle-area"... and a "thank you" would have been appropriate ;)

Answer (score 0):

@Amin check the line % plot triangle. You might have missed '%' which comments the line or the variable triangle_area is used as triangle alone.

Comment: Yap... nevertheless this "answer" should have better been a comment ;)